# Fan gate for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Couple years ago I created an app with fan gate.
Everything forked fine..
That code doesn't worked now, so I tryed many ways, but nothing works, also all tutorials and articles that I found are old. Facebook disabled fan gating or what's wrong?
If not (I hope so), can you tell me where I can find useful information?
Many thanks in advance.. Please don't tell me that it's impossible ))

Comment: well there has been a lot of changes in FB api in last couple of years and perhaps you are using old code so you may need to explore a bit on Graph API !!

Comment: So it's possible, isn't it? I tryed several new codes.. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using the PHP SDK and the "getSignedRequest" method:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest/

Make a `var_dump($signed_request)` and you will see the fan status as one of the parameters.

PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

This method is working since years without any changes. So if you are doing it like that, maybe you just need to update your PHP SDK.

Comment: if ($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if ($signed_request->page->liked) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
               echo "1";
    }
}

Comment: is it so simple? Where should I put the page ID?

Comment: why would you need to put the page id somewhere? just use the php sdk and try the getSignedRequest method as i posted. it only works on a page app though. it is indeed that simple.

Comment: btw, you echo "1" both times...just saying ;)